# How to reduce gap/space between chart border and pie chart

Tags: jfreechart

I want to increase the width of pie chart by reducing the gap between the chart border and chart. How to achieve this?

Comment: Vijayalakshmi, to put it less diplomatically: you have been given some good answers. Accept them. (And you should read @trashgod's link for more details.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`setInteriorGap()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/PiePlot.html#setInteriorGap%28double%29) method "controls the space between the edges of the pie plot and the plot area itself." Smaller values reduce the gap.